# Failing at deducing variadic template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, variadic-templates

What is the fundamental reason that explains that the following test case fails to compile :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename Type, typename... Args> 
void apply(std::vector<Type> &v, Args... args, void(*algo)(Type*, Type*, Args...))
{
    algo(&*v.begin(), &*v.end(), args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10, 50);
    apply(v, 3, std::iota);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
       std::cout<<v[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround for the function prototype ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is, as the compiler error states:

> parameter packs must be at the end of the parameter list.

In other words, you must declare your function so `Args ... args` is the last argument in the list.

Also, I don't believe the compiler will infer the type of a template function that uses template templates the way you use them, so you'll have to explicitly specify the template:

```
apply<int, int>(v, std::iota, 3); // or something
```

[Ideone of your snipped with proposed modifications](http://ideone.com/kqcslg)

Comment: `apply<int>(v, std::iota, 3);` [is fine, too](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6809848b76a05fc6c5f947d36c8063b7) -- no need to specify `Args...` manually. (And there are no template template parameters here.)

Comment: template template is the wrong word, but I can't think of the right one.